# How to use trans + format together in twig?

Tags: php, twig

I need some help with twig.

I get the following row: `{{ 'Hi' | trans}}, {{username}} }}!`

But, i need something like this: `{{ 'Hi, %s' | format(username} | trans }}`

How i can implement this ? Row above not working properly

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `{{ ('Hi, %s' | format(username)) | trans }}`

Comment: @DarkBee it is not working :(

Answer (score 1):

It's about the order.
Twig renders the string from left to right.

So your string:

```
{{ 'Hi, %s' | format(username} | trans }}
```

Gets first converted to:

```
{{ 'Hi, username' | trans }}
```

And, as you don't have the translation for each username, it doesn'nt work. You need to fetch first the translation containing the placeholder, and then replace it.

Try instead:

```
{{ 'Hi' | trans | format(username} }}
```

And in your translation files, the key **Hi** should include the **%s**

```
Hi: Hello %s!
```

and for each language:

```
Hi: Hola %s!
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems i found a solution for this problem. Maybe it`s just a one is possible variants.

The following row works for me

```
{{ 'Hi' | trans ~ ',' ~ ' %s' | format(username) }}
```